# Redirect if claim is missing in RequiresAuthentication

Tags: nancy

I'm working on setting up two-factor in my application and I'm trying to make it redirect back to the verification page if the user is logged in but not verified (I'm keeping track of if the user is verified in the sessions table which is added to ClaimsPrincipal 'IsVerified').

The problem i'm having is the example I am using from the documentation doesn't seem to be working properly:

```
public static class ModuleSecurity
    {
        public static string[] ExcludedPaths = { "/", "/login", "/login/verify", "/admin/settings", "/login/tf/setup" };

        public static void RequiresAuthentication(this NancyModule module)
        {
            module.Before.AddItemToEndOfPipeline(RequiresAuthentication);
        }

        private static Response RequiresAuthentication(NancyContext context)
        {
            // Check if user is authenticated
            if (context.CurrentUser == null)
                return new Response() { StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized };

            if (context.CurrentUser.FindFirst("RequireVerification")?.Value == "True" && context.CurrentUser.FindFirst("IsVerified")?.Value != "True" && !ExcludedPaths.Any(x => x.ToLower() == context.Request.Path.ToLower()))
                return new Response().WithHeader("Location", "/login/verify").WithContentType("text/html").WithStatusCode(HttpStatusCode.SeeOther);

            return null;
        }
    }
```

Putting break points in I see the "module.Before.AddItemToEndOfPipeline" is executed but it is not executing the other method I have.

Comment: What I mean is it is not executing the second method listed in the code example above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then problem was I was adding this to the BEFORE pipeline but i'm calling this.RequiresClaims after the route was triggered (so I needed the AFTER pipeline). I was able to do this by adding the extensions and using the module.AddBeforeOrExecute option.